# sqlalchemy: dividing timedelta column by float giving strange results

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, timedelta

I'm trying to perform some manipulation on a column inside the query. I want to divide a timedelta column by 60. Unfortunately it is giving strange results.

In my query I return two datetimes, the timedelta between these two datetimes, and the timedelta between these two datetimes divided by 2. An example of the output:

```
(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 8), 
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 7, 32), 
datetime.timedelta(0, 444), 
Decimal('362.0000'))
```

However, the timedelta 444 divided by 2 does not equal 362.0000. But this is what sqlalchemy is giving me. Is there anyway to get the correct result?

Its important to do this manipulation in the query because I am also trying to use the above as a subquery and average over the results but I'm getting strange averages back as well.

Here is my query:

```
    sub = session.query( 
                        merge.c.time_received,
                        merge.c.time_sent,
                        func.timediff(
                            merge.c.time_sent,
                            merge.c.time_received
                        ),
                        func.timediff(
                            merge.c.time_sent,
                            merge.c.time_received
                        ) / 2.0
                    ). \
                    filter(
                        merge.c.time_received != None,
                        merge.c.time_sent != None,
                    ). \
                    limit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happens when you divide [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html) by a number. But maybe converting it to `seconds` first using [`TIME_TO_SEC(time)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) will do the trick.

*I assumed mysql` is used.*